# What is the use of this "$x **= $n" Operator

Tags: perl, operators

In Perl I know that we can use `"$x *= $n"` for multiplying `x` with `n`. So I mistakenly used `"**="` and output seemed to be very high number for very small values of `"n"`. What does that operator do ?

Please do not say that it is just for exponential. It is not. please verify using the syntax I have shown

Comment: *"Please do not say that it is just for exponential"* -- Why not? That's exactly what it is.

Comment: do you have any counter example? (ie - one in which it doesn't work like an exponent)

Comment: Downvoted for this: "Please do not say that it is just for exponential. It is not."  If you have a specific example in which it is not working as expected, you need to show that example and the results you get.

Comment: @Keith Thompson and others : as stated by ikegami, this not "[exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function)", but "[exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation)". So VAR121 is not so wrong ;)

Answer (score 11):

It is the exponentiation operator:

```
perl -e 'print 2**3';
```

prints 8

So, `$a **= n` is equivalent to `$a = $a**n` which is equivalent with `$a raised to the power n`

Comment: Try this `perl -e '$a = 4; $a **= $a; print $a '`

Comment: Perhaps a little more obvious: `perl -e '$x = 2; $n = 20; $x **= $n; print "$x\n"'`

Comment: @VAR121 : `4 ** 4 == 4 * 4 * 4 * 4 == 256`. That is what your snippet returns.

Comment: @VAR121: You are right in the sense of "$a power $n" is not exp($n). The term "power" operator should be used here instead.

Comment: @Ouki, huh??? That's completely wrong. The mathematical operation it performs is "[exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation)". The operation is not called power, that's the name of the RHS arg in exponentiation.

Comment: @ikegami: my fault ... "power" is a weak translation from my mother language ... and the mix with "[exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function)" and "exponentiation". I think that wat VAR121 did as well ;)

Comment: this answer is a candidate for me to earn a Reversal gold medal - if you want to help me achieve that, please upvote the answer. Thx :)